# Overwriting a variable when inheriting from a parent class

Tags: c++, oop

I have a simple class

```
class Foo {
    public:
        float m;
        Foo();
}

Foo::Foo(){
    this->m = 1.0f;
}
```

Then I'm extending it with

```
class Bar: public Foo {
    public:
        float m;
        Bar()
}

Bar::Bar(){
    this->m = 10.0f;
}
```

I then instantiate `Bar()` but `Bar.m` is still 1.0f. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: "I then instantiate `Bar()` but `Bar.m` is still `1.0f`. Is there a reason for this?"  Well, how do you do this?  Please provide a complete program that demonstrates your problem.  (Preferably one that compiles--your current problem uses both 'm' and 'n' as variable names; it can't be both...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, you cannot override a field.  Only methods can be overridden.  Consequently, your declaration of the variable `m` in the class `Bar` is a new field that hides the base class `Foo`'s version of `m`.

If you want to access `Foo`'s `m` from `Bar`, then you could use this syntax:

```
Bar::Bar(){
    this->Foo::m = 10.0f;
}
```

Which explicitly tells the compiler to write to `Foo`'s version of `m`.  Alternatively, you can drop the `this->` and just write

```
Bar::Bar(){
    Foo::m = 10.0f;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I want Bar.m to hold a new value, not one which was grabbed from the base class.

Comment: @dotty: Why can't you give the variable a new name?!

Comment: Foo.m will hold a position. Bar is obviously wants to hold a different position. But still wants it to be called m.

Comment: @dotty- I think you may be confused on how inheritance works.  When you inherit from `Foo`, you automatically inherit the field `m`.  This means that you don't need to declare your own version inside of `Bar`, and in fact it's almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: I need to change the inherited value m on the inherited object.

Comment: @dotty- In that case, the syntax I've posted should do it.  However, why are you giving both the base class and derived class a field with the same name?  This can easily lead to confusion about which of the fields you're writing to, as shown here.

Comment: @dotty: You mean you need `Bar()` to set `Foo::m` to a different value? In that case, just remove the extra `m` from `Bar`, and leave everything else as it is; then the constructor of `Bar` will set `Foo::m` to the value you want. Unless you actually want a second variable, in which case ignore me and do what this answer says.

Comment: @dotty: Then remove `float m;` from `Bar` (since you don't want a new `m`, you want the inherited one that every `Foo` has), and remove the `this->` from the constructor (since it's implicit).

Comment: Sorry, this was working. I apologise for wasting your time, and thanks.